Double Authentication with NextAuth (i.e ecommere and foundation login) in next.js and ts
Double Authentication with NextAuth: Issues with Multiple Routes
I'm working on a Next.js application that involves two different authentication flows using NextAuth: one for an e-commerce platform and another for a foundation platform. I have set up two separate authentication options, but I'm running into issues when trying to handle multiple API routes in the route.ts file.
Problem: When trying to authenticate, I encounter an error: No response is returned from route handler. I'm not sure how to properly handle multiple NextAuth API routes.
Here's my setup:
api/auth/[...nextauth]/options.ts
typescript
Copy code
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import dbConnect from "@/dbconfig/dbConnect";
import UserModel from "@/models/user.models";
import DonationModel from "@/models/donation.models";
import { ApiResponse } from "@/helpers/ApiResponse";

// E-commerce Authentication Options
export const ecommerceAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'ecommerce-credentials',
            name: 'E-commerce Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any): Promise<any> {
                await dbConnect();
                try {
                    const user = await UserModel.findOne(
                        { email: credentials.email },
                    );
                    if (!user) {
                        return new Response(
                            JSON.stringify(new ApiResponse(false, 400, {}, "User not found")),
                            { status: 400 }
                        );
                    }
                    if (!user.isVerified) {
                        return new Response(
                            JSON.stringify(new ApiResponse(false, 400, {}, "User not verified")),
                            { status: 400 }
                        );
                    }

                    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password);
                    if (isPasswordCorrect) {
                        return user;
                    }
                  
                    return new Response(
                        JSON.stringify(new ApiResponse(false, 400, {}, "Incorrect password")),
                        { status: 400 }
                    );
                } catch (error) {                    
                    return new Response(
                        JSON.stringify(new ApiResponse(false, 400, {}, "Error while login")),
                        { status: 400 }
                    );
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token._id = user._id?.toString();
                token.userName = user.userName;
                token.role = user.role;
                token.platform = "ecommerce";
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user._id = token._id;
            session.user.userName = token.userName;
            session.user.role = token.role;
            session.platform = token.platform;
            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/ecommerce-signin',
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

// Foundation Authentication Options
export const foundationAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'foundation-credentials',
            name: 'Foundation Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any): Promise<any> {
                await dbConnect();
                try {
                    const user = await DonationModel.findOne({
                        $or: [
                            { email: credentials.email },
                        ]
                    });
                    if (!user) {
                        throw new Error('No user found with this email');
                    }
                           
                    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password);
                    if (isPasswordCorrect) {
                        return user;
                    }
                    throw new Error('Incorrect Password');
                } catch (error) {
                    throw new Error("Email or Password is incorrect");
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token._id = user._id?.toString();
                token.donorName = user.userName;
                token.role = user.role;
                token.platform = "foundation";
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user._id = token._id;
            session.user.userName = token.userName;
            session.user.role = token.role;
            session.platform = token.platform;
            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/foundation-signin',
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { ecommerceAuthOptions, foundationAuthOptions } from "./options";
import { ApiResponse } from "@/helpers/ApiResponse";

async function handleAuth(req: NextRequest) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
    const platform = searchParams.get('platform');

    let options;
    if (platform === 'ecommerce') {
        options = ecommerceAuthOptions;
    } else if (platform === 'foundation') {
        options = foundationAuthOptions;
    } else {
        return new Response(
            JSON.stringify(new ApiResponse(false, 400, {}, "Invalid platform")),
            { status: 400 }
        );
    }

    return NextAuth(options);
}

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    return handleAuth(req);
}

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
    return handleAuth(req);
}

What I Need Help With
How can I properly handle multiple authentication options in NextAuth within a single API route?
Why am I encountering the No response is returned from route handler error, and how can I fix it?
Any help or guidance on properly structuring this setup would be greatly appreciated!
